# AngularJS using $resource to get json data from API, getting undefined

Tags: angularjs, undefined

Im getting undefined, undefined from ipCity and ipCountry

but i cant understand why.

```
weatherApp.service('cityService', function ($resource) {

    var ipLocation = $resource("http://ipinfo.io", {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get: {method: "JSONP"}});
    var ipResult = ipLocation.get();
    var ipCity = ipResult.city;
    var ipCountry = ipResult.country;

    console.log(ipResult);

    this.city = ipCity + ", " + ipCountry;
})
```

LOG:

```
d {$promise: d, $resolved: false}
$promise: d
$resolved: true
city: "Toronto"
country: "CA"
hostname: "CPE00fc8d503cf3-CM00fc8d503cf0.cpe.net.cable.rogers.com"
ip: "99.232.37.198"
loc: "43.6555,-79.3626"
org: "AS812 Rogers Cable Communications Inc."
postal: "M5A"
region: "Ontario"
__proto__: d
```

So im basically getting the data from the API but i cant use the data into my service.

Comment: you aren't using the correct syntax here.  from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource: "•HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`".  essentially, `.get` is async, and won't immediately have a value.

Comment: so how do you explain the log from ipResult?

Comment: because the log is showing a promise.  by the time you actually inspect the console, the promise has returned, but it hasn't returned yet at the time you try to assign the variables.  It even shows `$resolved: false` first, then `$resolved: true` on the second log.

Comment: you need to create a success function handler for assigning your variables, not assign them in parallel with the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide a callback function.  Also, be aware that the data will not be in your service immediately.

```
var self = this;
    ipResult.$promise.then(function(data)
    {
       var ipCity = data.city;
       var ipCountry = data.country;

        console.log(data);

        self.city = ipCity + ", " + ipCountry;  
    });
```

Comment: how can i wait for the data to be in my service, so i can display it? right now i cant display it since its not there when the page loads.

Comment: I put a plunkr here as an example...http://plnkr.co/edit/bxvBqlkqC8olrw7BvOuD

cityService.promise.then(function()
  {
    $scope.city = cityService.city;
  });